# How to call all values outside which is within foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

I want to call **$images** values anywhere outside the loop.

```
$images = DB::table('images')->where('status', 'active')->get();
@foreach ($images as $img) {
    $title = $images->title;
    echo $title;
@endforeach
}
```

**Output:** Apple Mango Banana Pine Grapes

Now I want to call all these values of **$title** within a division which is outside the loop.

```
<div>
{{ $title }}
</div>
```

Comment: No @DirkJ.Faber mine is simple and straight forward, the one pointed by you is taking me here n there.

Comment: Yes, it requires reading. For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Just read the question and answer and you'll understand what scope is and how to solve your problem.

Comment: Are you wanting to output the `title` individually, or all together in a single line?

Comment: @Peppermintology in single line.

Comment: You can achieve this without a `foreach` using the [`implode`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-implode) method on the `$images` collection. I can't provide a better answer as some others have decided to close your question.